# Just upgraded from laravel 5.2 to 5.4: return data with object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Look at the following expression:

```
        return $user->boxes()->get();
```

In my laravel 5.2 the data for the following example was:

```
boxes [
...array of boxes
]
```

*Accessed by: response.json().boxes*

Another example:

```
$info = $this->with('zone.world')
        ->find($this->id);
```

Accessed by user.data (this is the User Model)
Now it's only data
since laravel 5.4 the returned data is only the array of the boxes:

[box1,box2,box3] without the "boxes" object above them.

*Accessed by: response.json()*

Because of this behavior, I have to change all my client api calls to get the array without thet object above it.

**Is there any way to change it to work back as 5.2?**

Comment: show boxes() code

Comment: what was your database fetch mode in Laravel 5.2  ?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski the main goal is that the response in 90% of my calls are changed, added another example

Comment: @PankitGami if you mean strict is set to false in both

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you not have a backup? Quite a lot has changed between 5.2 and 5.4. You should really read the changelog before updating if there's something likely to break.

Comment: Ofcourse I do, but I need to upgrade since I could get the password recovery to work with version 5.4, got some strange errors in my 5.2

Comment: @TheUnreal In Laravel < 5.4 there were support for Database Fetch mode (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/config/database.php#L16) which they have removed in Laravel 5.4 (https://github.com/laravel/docs/blob/5.4/upgrade.md#fetch-mode).